# Make a react native app which not use expo run on web

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

I have a react-native App which is not using Expo and runs on android and iOS. Is it possible to make it run on Web? I found multiple [projects](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/) for this purpose but I am not sure if those projects are aimed to be used only with Expo projects or not. I use multiple android and iOS modules in my app, I can't imagine how those modules will be converted to run on web. Any advise? Is what I am trying to do is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using native modules with android or IOS specific functionality then you'll have to find a replacement that supports web, (or keep them and use something else for web).

Also no need to stay away from expo modules, expo modules can be used outside of expo too, here's how you can set them up: https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/

I'd suggest you listen to some of Fernando Rojo's talks about this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0FfvIuSouTU&ab_channel=SoftwareMansion